# How to add different action filters on the derived controller actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My controllers have a same action with different authorization filter.

```
public class RoomAController:Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "RoomAEditors")]
    public ActionResult SaveNote()
    {
       ...
    }
}

public class RoomBController:Controller
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "RoomBEditors")]
    public ActionResult SaveNote()
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

The code of `SaveNote` are exactly the same in both controllers. So I want to place it into a base controller like this.

```
public abastract class BaseController:Controller
{
    public ActionResult SaveNote()
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

With this base controller in place, how can I add the action filter in the individual controllers?

```
public class RoomBController:BaseController
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "RoomBEditors")]
    // how to add different authorization filters on the SaveNote action?
}
```

On my abstract base controller, there is a `SaveNote` action.

Comment: I think @Skyler's answer is on the dot, although I would suggest you rethink your design. This feels more like a code smell to me...

Comment: Two options I can think of off the top of my head:
Option 1: override the method
Option 2: use a custom authorization attribute that derives from `AuthorizeAttribute` and have some logic that can reference a variable or method to determine which role to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the SaveNote method in your BaseController and override it in RoomA and RoomB controllers using the proper Authorization filter roles.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    virtual public ActionResult SaveNote()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class RoomAController : BaseController
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "RoomAEditors")]
    public override ActionResult SaveNote()
    {
        return base.SaveNote();
    }
}

public class RoomBController : BaseController
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "RoomBEditors")]
    public override ActionResult SaveNote()
    {
        return base.SaveNote();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll call SaveNote() on the BaseController (Base) inside of each of the SaveNote() actions.